# brew mysql5.6 mysql_install_db error

Tags: mysql, homebrew

Im trying to install mysql with homebrew.
Installing it was successfully completed, but "mysql_install_db" shows an error saying
"/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--?'"
I have no idea why it occurs.. Anyone please help..

```
* unset TMPDIR
* mysql_install_db --verbose --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
Installing MySQL system tables...2013-06-24 20:49:40 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-06-24 20:49:40 7fff7c0fe180 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 300.0M
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 1626304
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--?'
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] Binlog end
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2013-06-24 20:49:40 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2013-06-24 20:49:41 32316 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626314
2013-06-24 20:49:41 32316 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sloved this problem. use this statement: `./scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql --no-defaults`